# How to configure efax-gtk 20.04?

Tags: fax

`hw-probe`  https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=7d09386126

The goal is to setup efax-gtk for a [HP 8440p laptop (lshw pastebin click here)](https://pastebin.com/raw/m8z8P2MQ):

[image]

`ls /dev` returns:

[image]

How does one determine serial device & lock file parameters to configure Modem Parameters in the first screenshot?

Comment: Probably you have to try configuring modem first and only then configure fax. Probe your computer at https://linux-hardware.org by downloading and executing their [AppImage tool](https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe/blob/master/README.md#appimage). Then share link to the probe here.

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for the `hw-probe` suggestion.  OP update with link to `hw-probe` results

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting